# Swift - cellForItemAtIndexPath unwrapping an Optional value when resizing image

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, resize-image

i need resize dynamically an imagView when scroll a collection view in swift...

i use this function for get event of scrolling:

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

                // get a reference to our storyboard cell
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
         let indexPathItem = self.items[indexPath.item]
         if let myImage = cell.myImage{
             myImage.image = imageWithImage(UIImage(named: indexPathItem)!, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: sizeImage, height: sizeImage))
         } 

      return cell
    }
```

and this function for resize image:

```
func imageWithImage(image:UIImage,scaledToSize newSize:CGSize)->UIImage{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize )
    image.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: newSize.width,height: newSize.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
}
```

debugged stops when run this line:

```
myImage.image = imageWithImage(UIImage(named: indexPathItem)!, scaledToSize: CGSize(width: sizeImage, height: sizeImage))
```

with error

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

working if i replace that with this:

```
cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named : self.items[indexPath.item])
```

But obviously it does not reduce the image

Can help me pls???

SOLUTION:
i need resize object "cell.myImage" and not "cell.myImage.image" so solved with:

```
  cell.myImage.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0,width:sizeImage,height:sizeImage)
```

and set mode of imageView into cell like aspect fit.

Comment: How you create `indexPathItem` object?

Comment: Oh yes... with this line: `let indexPathItem = self.items[indexPath.item]` items it's my array with the name of images

Comment: Do you really need to be resizing your image? It seems like your scrolling will suffer, why not just fit the image to the imageView?

Comment: Yes it's same but the import it's resize imageView like cell with my solution: cell.myImage.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0,width:sizeImage,height:sizeImage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use safer code like below to avoid crashes while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCell

        cell.myImage?.image = imageWithImage(UIImage(named: self.items[indexPath.item]), scaledToSize: CGSize(width: sizeImage, height: sizeImage))

        return cell
    }

    func imageWithImage(image:UIImage?,scaledToSize newSize:CGSize)->UIImage?{

        guard let drawImage = image else {

            return nil
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize )
        drawImage.drawInRect(CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: newSize.width,height: newSize.height))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    }
```

your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` code is incomplete below line

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as!
```

so I have added `YourCell` for example.

Comment: Yes i correct my code now... YourCell is MyCollectionViewCell

Comment: i try your code but with "return newImage?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)" in function i see my image colored by blue... 
if I remove that line compiles but does not work... 
the images are still big – Ray13 14 mins ago

Comment: actually you can able to return newImage alone and no need to call imageWithRenderingMode, if you don't want it as template image really.

Comment: now i do but not working... compiles but does not show image resized...

Comment: okkkk! I know the problem! This code work but with this we can resize image into imageview and not imageview! I need resize the space of imageview into cell

Comment: ok. cool. Also you can use UIImageView content mode to aspectFit to place an image with aspect ratio.

Comment: Find solution!!! 
  cell.myImage.frame = CGRect(x:0.0,y:0.0,width:sizeImage,height:sizeImage)